# Is there an R package for nonlinear mixed effects model with spatial autocorrelation?

Tags: r, spatial, nonlinear-regression, mixed-model

I want to fit a nonlinear mixed effects model  for repeated measures data. The subjects on which the measures were repeated are spatially structured. Is there a package in R for this? I also have access to Stata, SAS, Mplus, and Mathematica.

Alternatively, is it acceptable to just include random effects for membership in a neighborhood of radius R, and maybe row and column effects (the spatial structure is 2D).

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to your alternate, it is not considered to be an attractive alternative, see [(Anselin and Arribas-Bel, 2013)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1435-5957.2012.00480.x/full)

Comment: At first as I was like, "Oh, it doesn't solve error term correlation? I guess that's okay for a first pass." Then I was like, "Oh, crap, it only works for discrete groups?" Dammit.